# Compile C++ project statically on redhat

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, redhat, static-linking

I'm trying to compile statically my C++ project on Redhat 7.3.

This is my script:

```
g++ -static -ldl -std=c++0x -O3 -fopenmp *.cpp -o main
```

But I obtain this error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl`

How can I fix it?
I think a library misses.

Comment: Redhat what? There have been many versions. Be precise.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I'm using Redhat 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-ldl` means `/usr/lib/libdl.so`
( Provided by `glibc-devel` )

the `-static -ldl` means `/usr/lib/libdl.a`
( Provided by `glibc-static` )

```
yum install glibc-devel glibc-static
```

Comment: Ok, I did it. But now I obtain /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ why?

Comment: now you must `yum intall libstdc++ libstdc++-static`